# Android layout: buttons at bottom similar to wechat

Tags: android, android-layout, wechat

For my app, I am trying to put buttons at the bottom of all activities similar to WeChat app as can be seen in below image:

[image]

Now one way I thought of is simply adding `<ImageButton>`s at bottom of each activities but I don't think WeChat does that because you can swipe between activities and there is no `onCreate` triggered, activities are always there that are simply switched when swiped or touched on specific button.

I did research and found out one can use `split action bar` or even `ViewFlipper`. Action bar splitting is out of question since button will be moved back to action bar for example in landscape mode since I want to have buttons always appear at bottom like WeChat. Another option I saw was `Tabbed` interface but I saw with it, it can appear below actionbar unlike WeChat where even actionbar is changed based on activity.

Question: Does anyone know what does WeChat use for this functionality so I can implement the same ?

Comment: Use a Fragment TabHost: http://envyandroid.com/archives/326/align-tabhost-at-bottom

Comment: I dont know what weChat is used for this but for sure you can get the same output using "Tabhost".

Comment: One RelativeLayout horizontally for all ImageButtons, and align it bottom, also you can set background color for the 'RelativeLayout'

Comment: I did something similar using ViewPager in the v4 support library and my own buttons at the bottom of the activity, handling the various callbacks myself. I needed to support down to api level 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
here is code main class 


public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTabs();

    }

    private void setTabs() {

        addTab("Wechat", R.drawable.tab_home, ShowList.class);
        addTab("Social", R.drawable.tab_search, UploadVideo.class);

        addTab("Contact Us", R.drawable.tab_home, Contactus.class);
        addTab("Setting", R.drawable.tab_search, DoNotDo.class);




    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}

here is xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, TabActivity was deprecated in api level 13. Docs suggest using fragments which are supported in v4 support library. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Answer (score 1):

One Idea is create **BaseActivity**, in which include the general design you prefer throughout the App. In other activities, extend **BaseActivity**. You can also extend **Activity** class in some activities where no need to show the buttons, such as **LoginActivity**.